# El código para mostrar el popUp al hacer click en el menuItem de la toolbar no haya el id del Fragmento

Tags: android, kotlin

Llevo ya tiempo tratando de solucionar el siguiente error. He probado todas las respuestas que he visto aquí en la comunidad de StackOverflow y no he conseguido éxito.

Este es el error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09022a
> (com.example.misaldo:id/donateLinear) for fragment
> popUpFragment{ed3fcff} (cffba6bd-b2af-48d8-a44a-29f7983d9d60
> id=0x7f09022a)

Este es el código del onCreate el cual vino por defecto al añadir un nuevo fragment en blanco.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pop_up, container, false)
```

Por aqui les dejo el codigo del MainActivity:

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            menuItem -> when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.info -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, ConfigActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    true
                }
            R.id.donar -> {
                val popUpFragment = popUpFragment()
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                transaction.replace(R.id.donateLinear, popUpFragment)
                transaction.addToBackStack(null)
                transaction.commit()
                true
            }

            else -> {
                false
            }
        }
```

Y por aqui les dejo el XML del fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/donateLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".popUpFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Estoy intentando hacer que al dar click en uno de los menuItem de la toolbar salga el popUp con los EditText y botones que añadire luego de solucionar este tedioso error..
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En ese fragment no hay ningún elemento con id donateLinear.

Comment: Si esta lo que disculpa. No habia copiado el fragment antiguo. Ya lo actualizo

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09022a
> (com.example.misaldo:id/donateLinear) for fragment
> popUpFragment{ed3fcff} (cffba6bd-b2af-48d8-a44a-29f7983d9d60
> id=0x7f09022a)

El problema se debe a que "no se puede encontrar la vista con id `donateLinear` para realizar el reemplazo del Fragment".

**Debes asegurar que el archivo `fragment_pop_up.xml` que cargas en `onCreateView()`** :

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pop_up, container, false)
```

**en realidad contenga el `FrameLayout`  con id `donateLinear`**.

Pudieras también cargar en `onCreate()` el layout que contiene tu `Framelayout`, esto usando el método `setContentView()` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Te sugiero revisar :
[**Transacciones de fragmentos**](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions?hl=es-419)